# Accessing php variables at different places in the same file

Tags: php

Consider the  code

```
<?php 
.....
.....
$error="abc";
......
?>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        .....
        <?php echo $error ?>
        .....
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to php. I want to access the same "error" variable at two parts in the same file. Is there any way to do so? Or I have to create another file with the "error" variable and then include it in the file where I need it again?

Comment: you can access the same variable an infinite number of times. if your saying you cant you need to post the actual code that does not work

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried accessing it?

You shouldn't have an issue doing something like the following:

```
<?php $error="abc"; ?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $error; ?>
    </body>
        <?php echo $error; // access #2 ?>
</html>
<?php echo $error; // access #3 ?>
```

**Note:** 
For the future, I would really try to improve the code format of your questions, mention what you tried to do already and provide more details about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the variable as many time as you need it if it's part of the same scope.

This will work:

```
<?php $foo = 'bar' ?>
<hr />
<?php echo $foo; ?>
```

This will not:

```
<?php
  function set_foo_variable() {
    $foo = 'bar';
  }

  set_foo_variable();
?>
<hr />
<?php echo $foo; ?>
```

Make sure your variable is always in the same scope AND is set.

Here's more documentation on PHP scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you should consider upvoting it and "acept it". [Here's how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ; To quote the post: "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."